# Didn't need an import statement

Tags: angular, typescript

My project footprint is:

```
project
|-app
  |-component1
    |-<angular component files>
  |-helpers
    |-helper1
      |-<plain typescript file>
|-node_modules
```

I was surprised that when I added the class for helper1 that I could use it in component1 (well Visual Studio Code had intellisense for it and doesn't complain) without needing an import statement.

Are classes searched automatically and included for typescript?

My tsconfig.json contains:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    }
}
```

Comment: @AliBaig it has nothing to do with the classes. you need to configure tsc to output module code. Otherwise it outputs normal files and you can use it like you would any old js file. Please share your tsconfig.json file for more details.

Comment: Added my tsconfig.json.

Comment: You can win typescript, but what build you have? Is it webpack, systemjs, rollup or something else?